# Iterate through a json list and get specific key and value with Python

Tags: python

I have a JSON list like this (it was a JSON response, the below is after i did `json.loads`)

```
[{'status': 'ok', 'slot': None, 'name': 'blah', 'index': 0, 'identify': 'off', 
'details': None, 'speed': None, 'temperature': None}, {'status': 'ok', 'slot': 
None, 'name': 'blah0', 'index': 0, 'identify': 'off', 'details': None, 
'speed': None, 'temperature': None}, {'status': 'ok', 'slot': None, 'name': 
'blah1', 'index': 1, 'identify': 'off', 'details': None, 'speed': None, 
'temperature': None}, {'status': 'ok', 'slot': None, 'name': 'blah2', 
'index': 2, 'identify': 'off', 'details': None, 'speed': None, 'temperature': 
None}, {'status': 'ok', 'slot': None, 'name': 'blah3', 'index': 3,
'identify': 'off', 'details': None, 'speed': None, 'temperature': None}]
```

I want to get both `name` and the `status` of the list, if `name='blah' or 'blah0' or 'blah1' or 'blah2' or 'blah3'`
Essentially, for all the matches i want to store all the `name` and `status` in separate variables to use it elsewhere. (can be dynamically creating variables or statically assigning them will also work for me)

I tried this, but doesn't seems to work the way i want.

```
for value in data:
   if value['name'] in ['blah', 'blah0', 'blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3']:
        print(value['name'], value['status'])
```

This prints out the `name` and `status` as a string one line below the other. But i want each name and status to be assigned to a variable so i can use it later. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: instead of assigning to variables, assign to a dictionary which you can then check with `your_dict.get('somekey', fallback_value)`

Comment: @JacobIRR can you put it as an answer? i'm really new to python :)  Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**
Try something like:

```
new_data = []
# Extract all the data and map them by name and status
for value in data:
    name = value.get("name")
    status = value.get("status")
    if name in ['blah', 'blah0', 'blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3']:
         new_data.append(dict(
            name=name,
            status=status))
```

**Option 1**

```
# loop through the new data
for data in new_data:
    print(data)

# OUTPUT:
{'name': 'blah', 'status': 'ok'}
{'name': 'blah0', 'status': 'ok'}
{'name': 'blah1', 'status': 'ok'}
{'name': 'blah2', 'status': 'ok'}
{'name': 'blah3', 'status': 'ok'}
```

**Option 2**

```
for data in new_data:
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, value)
#OUTPUT:
name blah
status ok
name blah0
status ok
name blah1
status ok
name blah2
status ok
name blah3
status ok
```

**Option 3**

```
for data in new_data:
        print(data['name'], data['status'])
#OUTPUT
blah ok
blah0 ok
blah1 ok
blah2 ok
blah3 ok
```

Comment: Thanks @Scircia. But how do i access each 'blah' and 'ok' separately? i would want to access each of them like,`blah`, `ok`, `blah0`, `ok`, etc

Comment: After the if you'll see 2 variables in the print statement. name & status. Thats how you can access them. If you like you could create a list with dictionaries and access each dictionary by key of the name. Let me edit it and hope you'll understand what i mean

Comment: thanks for editing. Ok, i know what i want now, just can you make it as a dict? Like, `'blah': 'ok'`, 'blah0': 'ok', etc. So that i can access both `blah` and `ok` separately. Sorry if i'm bugging you too much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want dynamic variables, but you can use a list comprehension. You should also take advantage of constant-cost set membership test:

```
keep = set(['blah', 'blah0', 'blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3'])
result = [(value['name'], value['status']) for value in data if value['name'] in keep]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('blah', 'ok'),
 ('blah0', 'ok'),
 ('blah1', 'ok'),
 ('blah2', 'ok'),
 ('blah3', 'ok')]
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
keep = set(['blah', 'blah0', 'blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3'])
result = {value['name']: value['status'] for value in data if value['name'] in keep}
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomothy32. But how do i access `'blah'` and `'ok'` separately? Like when i do `print (result[0])` it prints the whole `('blah', 'ok')`.

Comment: @Bharath `result[0][0]` and `result[0][1]`